# Make my filter the last in the grails plugin

Tags: spring, grails, spring-security, servlet-filters

I have regular servlet filter in my grails plugin.
I put it in the end of my filters section in myPluginGrailsPlugin.groovy

```
filters[filters.size() - 1] + {
        filter {
            'filter-name'('MyFilter')
            'filter-class'('com.my.app.MyFilter')
        }
    }
```

But when I'm debugging it, my filter is not the last.
I want to get current user name, but this information is not accessible yet, because some Spring filters should be called before my filter.

How can I put my filter in the end of chain?